# How to stop loop with button click

Tags: android, android-button

how do i stop a loop with a button?

onClick creates some dynamic checkboxes and in the loop i want to check if they are checked.

this is the code i tried so far.

*edit: rephrasing question.*

i need a loop which runs until the user presses a button, something like this

while(!button.isPressed()){}

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragen);    

            View weiterButton = findViewById(R.id.weiterButton);
        weiterButton.setOnClickListener(this);    

}



public void onClick(View v) 
{
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.weiterButton:
                 View weiterButton = findViewById(R.id.weiterButton);
                 weiterButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                 while(!weiterButton.isPressed())
                 {
                     // do things
                 }
           break;
}
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question,it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. What exactly are you doing in the loop? I hope you're not trying to block the main UI thread until the user checks one of the `CheckBoxes`(?!?) as this will get you the ANR dialog?

Comment: actually i'm trying to do that :/